# Communicating between C# and Python

Tags: c#, python

I'm having a little bit of a problem with communication between C# and Python.

I'm passing some arguments to Python from C# using the following hacky code:

```
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Substring(6);
    string pyUnintelligibilityPath = "\\unintelligibility.py";
    string pyNeuralPredictorPath = "\\predict.py";
    string clf = "\\clf.pkl";

    public double unintelligibleProbability(string pyLocation, string msg)
    {
        FileStream tempMessage = new FileStream(path + "\\tempMessage.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempMessage);
        writer.WriteLine(msg);
        writer.Close();

        string args = path + pyUnintelligibilityPath + " " + path + clf + " " + path + "\\tempMessage.txt" + " " + path + "\\tempCoefficient.txt";
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = pyLocation;
        start.Arguments = args;
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        start.RedirectStandardError = false;
        Process process = Process.Start(start);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        double unintelligibility = Convert.ToDouble(File.ReadAllText(path + "\\tempCoefficient.txt").Replace('.', ','));

        return unintelligibility;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this solution is very inefficient in my situation (not even due to the fact that I don't have any code that checks if the file changes as that will be added later and it's not really the problem I'm having).

The thing is, the Python code takes a very long time to load the .pkl file before it can actually do anything useful (don't mind the unnecessary imports, I just reused this thing from some other file):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer, CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF, TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import codecs
import sys

clf = joblib.load(sys.argv[1])

data = codecs.open(sys.argv[2], encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
text = data.readlines()
data.close()
text = [x.strip() for x in text] 

f = open(sys.argv[3], mode='w')

proba = clf.predict_proba(text)
for i in range(0, len(text)):
    meme = proba[i,:]
    memeNum = meme[1]/(meme[0]+meme[1])
    f.write(str(memeNum.round(4)) + "\n")
f.close()
```

My question is, is it possible to re-write the code in a way that allows me to keep a Python script running in the background and C# just passing commands to it since reinitializing the script every single time I need to process a single message takes way too long.

Keep in mind that I would really like to not to use any network protocol-based solutions as that overcomplicates things to a point where it's not really worth it to me, I really don't care about doing this remotely or anything like that, everything's happenning locally. However, if it's the only option, then I guess I have no choice.

Comment: Too bad you dont want to use network-based solutions. Sockets seem to be a good idea. If the data isnt to complex this could be implemented pretty fast.

Comment: the data is just strings that may containt utf-8 characters with length anywhere ranging from 1 to 500 characters

Comment: Id really try TCP Sockets for that.

Comment: Outside of network-based protocols, there's also OS-specific ones for IPC; if you don't mind middleware, message queues (such as ZeroMQ) provide a means of setting that up easily. (Although e.g. ZeroMQ won't support IPC on Windows, but TCP on a loopback will work just the same, except it fails your network-protocol-less criterion.)

Comment: if using TCP really is the easiest solution, I might give it a shot I guess, where should I look for to get info on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try IronPython, it's a .Net - Python bridge. Or basicly you can access .net stuff from python or interpret python from c#.

Comment: could i run into compatibility issues if i'm using libraries like scikit-learn?

Comment: i'm not sure about that, i guess the best way is to try it.
btw i can recommend you this page https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages

Comment: Ironpython only support python2.x AFAIK